# Postgres: Getting the highest matching log associated with a record?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I store a log as follows:

```
LOG
ID | MODELID | EVENT
1  | 1       | Upped
2  | 1       | Downed
3  | 2       | Downed
4  | 1       | Upped
5  | 2       | Multiplexed
6  | 1       | Removed
```

Then I have the models as:

```
MODEL
ID | NAME
1  | Model 1
2  | Model 2
```

I want to end up with the LOG entry with the HIGHEST ID in LOG associated with a model as a result:

```
NAME    | EVENT
Model 1 | Removed
Model 2 | Multiplexed
```

A simple join gives me all the results:

```
SELECT * FROM MODEL AS M LEFT JOIN LOG AS L 
ON L.MODELID = M.ID
```

But this gives me all the records. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT M.NAME,L.EVENT FROM LOG L INNER JOIN MODEL M
ON L.MODELID = M.ID 
WHERE L.ID IN 
(
  SELECT MAX(ID) FROM LOG GROUP BY MODELID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a subselect. Let's start by breaking down the problem.

First you want the HIGHEST ID for a given MODELID in the LOG table.

```
SELECT
    MODELID
    ,MAX(ID)
FROM
    LOG
GROUP BY
    MODELID
```

Now if we use this as a subselect (virtual table) then you can also get the model name.

E.g.

```
SELECT
    M.NAME
    ,L.EVENT
FROM
    MODEL M
    ,(
        SELECT
            MODELID AS MODELID
            ,MAX(ID) AS MAXID
        FROM
            LOG
        GROUP BY
            MODELID
    ) S
    ,LOG L
WHERE
    M.ID = S.MODELID
    AND L.ID = S.MAXID
```

Give that a go (I haven't tested it myself).

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    select M.NAME,L.EVENT, row_number() over(partition by M.ID order by L.ID desc) as row_num
    from MODEL as M
        inner join LOG as L on L.MODELID = M.ID
)
select NAME, EVENT from cte
where row_num = 1
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c2d47/2) example

I'm not sure about PostgreSQL, but I think that this one should be faster than counting `max`, because it's just one pass instead of two. Also this ones generalizes better - you could order by more than one column.